# Calculate delta of traffic for the given $__range in Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I can't wrap my head around how I can calculate the total http traffic generated between two specific timestamps defined by $__range.

I'm aware of posts like this one but I can't see them actually answering the question that I'm posing here:

[Get delta between two custom timestamps in Prometheus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56148125/get-delta-between-two-custom-timestamps-in-prometheus)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible

```
     delta(vss_device_number[$__range])
```

Credit goes to @valyala for this tip.